# Display axis labels below mosaicplot

Tags: r

I'm trying to change the default settings on displaying the x values at the top of the plot to the bottom of the plot.

Here is a small example:

```
Betta <- c(1,12,23,20)
dim(Betta) <- c(2,2) 
dimnames(Betta) <- list(Temperature = c("28", "25"), Flare = c("Yes", "No"))
mosaicplot(x = Betta, main = "Title")
```

[image]

To make things clear, I'm trying to move the temperature values 28 and 25 to the bottom on the graph, right above x axis "Temperature".

Appreciate the help!

Comment: What do you want to change in wrt "x" settings, it is not clear from your quesstion?

Comment: sry, what i want is to move values 28 and 25 to the bottom of the graph, so it would be right above x axis label (which is temperature in this case)

Comment: you can try package `ggmosaic` but you have to use `data.frame` instead of contingency table.

Comment: I really don't know how to implement ggmosaic, sorry Mamoun, an hour ago was the first time seeing R code. I saw there are couple of attributes that can be change inside mosaicplot, like the title of the table, title of the x/y label, but I couldn't figure out how to move the x-value to the bottom of the table. I would appreciate if you attach the code solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use package `ggmosaic` with the example below

```
df <- as.data.frame(as.table(Betta)) # first, transform the contingency table into a data.frame
library(ggmosaic)
ggplot(data=df)+
    geom_mosaic(aes(weight=Freq,x=product(Temperature), fill=Flare))+
     labs(x="Temperature")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This solved my problem.

Comment: glad to have your feedback